# Having issues on getting ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync to work

Tags: react-native, expo, imagepicker

I’m currently working in React Native trying to open the camera to let the user add an image. I want to do this with the ImagePicker library and the function *launchCameraAsync*. The problem is that, when I try to execute the function, I get this error:

> Error occurred while launching the camera: [Error: Call to function
> ‘ExponentImagePicker.launchCameraAsync’ has been rejected. → Caused
> by: User rejected permissions]

What’s weird is that, just before calling *launchCameraAsync*, i call *requestCameraPermissionsAsync* and it returns granted = true, meaning that the permissions to use the camera are provided.

This is my code:

```
  const openCamera = async () => {
    const status = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(status);
    try {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        quality: 1,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      });
      if (!result.canceled) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error occurred while launching the camera: ", error);
    }
  };
```

I really do not know how to proceed from here, and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`requestCameraPermissionsAsync` returns `granted=true` means that the app has been granted permission by the user at some point in the past, but the user can still revoke the permission later.

Did you add the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `Info.plist`?

Check if the camera permission is granted using the `getCameraPermissionsAsync`. If camera permission is not granted, request it with `requestCameraPermissionsAsync`

```js
const openCamera = async () => {
  const { status } = await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync();
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    alert('Sorry, we need camera permissions to make this work!');
    return;
  }
  try {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error occurred while launching the camera: ", error);
  }
};
```